# Smooth Zooming?

Tags: 3d-view

I just got a Logitech G502 Proteus Core mouse (yay!). It has a mode where you can set the scroll wheel to be smooth instead of having "clicks" like usual scroll wheels. However, when it is set to smooth mode, blender still pretends as if there are "clicks" when I am zooming in. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19757/599

Comment: It's actualy the other way around. Blender doesn't pretend there are clicks, because there really are clicks. Smooth scrolling is a software trick and the mouse is just pretending there are no clicks. Off-topic: also you should have gotten Roccat Tyon, had both and the roccat is better for almost same money.

Comment: @Jerryno Thanks, I get it now. Also, the roccat tyon is not better. I considered it, but: the sensor is significantly worse, I've heard some of the buttons are very hard to reach comfortably, and it does not have the smooth scrolling feature. Additionally, the tyon is not available at Best Buy, and I had a few gift cards for Best Buy.

Comment: Yes, the sensor is worse but on a pad which I consider a must there is no difference. Some buttons are hard to reach true, but that takes just getting used to and I use many of them instead some shortcuts in blender. I don't like the smooth scrolling, and roccat has the best clicking scroll wheel I had. I see you did your research and made an informed decision. Still love the Tyon but the G502 is hell of a mouse too.

Answer (score 6):

As a side note, you can hold "Ctrl" + "MiddleMouseBtn" and drag in the viewport for smooth zoom.
Search for zoom in shortcut preferences.